# How do I change the maxlength of a password

Tags: html

I am playing an online quest game and on one level I have got a page where I have to enter the username and password. I know the password, but the html code of the page only allows a 20 letter password and the password has 22 letters. So how do I change the max length of the password? 
here are the snapshots:[image]

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a question for the support of that particular game? Unless this is actually a game about learning how to hack?

Comment: Seems that html page (which of course is the server) has an issue. Unless you know the server db password, you can't change it in my opinion. You may have to contact the admin

Comment: Is this your page? The developers would have made a limit by themselves. not something you could change

Comment: Well its not exactly about hacking,it has riddle and stuffs except this one question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they don't use javascript like your picture shows. use Firefox , right-click and inspect element. you can double click the source and change it real-time. although i am not sure that it will take effect because like @drewness said, the server may be set up not to accept it.

i say Firefox because internet explorers is clumsy, and Chrome's doesn't let you actively select elements like Firefox's does.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using Javascript's `setAttribute`.

```
pwdField.setAttribute("maxlength", 128);
```

Of course this will just change it in the browser and the form may not validate if it is limited on the server.

Comment: @user239321 - It would go in a `<script>` tag. Or you could do it through the console in FireBug.